# How to resize the RelativeLayout or any other Layout in Android?

Tags: android, layout, resize

I have a RelativeLayout defined in xml and I call the setContentView(R.layout.relativeLAyout) for displaying in Activity.

Now, if I want to resize this RelativeLayout then can it be done and if yes, then can someone let me know how?

The inner components can be resized relatively to the parent.

Is this actually possible?

Regards
Sunil

Comment: I only have a rough idea of what you have in mind, but yes, resizing space allocated to most elements is possible. For better advice, post some actual layout.xml.

Answer (score 0):

As to the inner components not resizing, make sure that both `android:layout_width` and and `android:layout_height` are set to fill_parent - then they should take up the space given to the parent.

Comment: I have used fill_parent only, then also will check it once again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

well if you use Eclipse, in the XML file, there at the bottom just switch to Graphical Layout.

and from there you can drag and drop payouts, Buttons etc :D
then in properties you can select add the pixels (200px )  on width/height